# Check if an element with a certain id and previous to an element with a certain class exists

Tags: jquery

i have a element with id='**dummyfield**' and there is div after it with class= '**dummydiv**'.
How can i know if **dummydiv** exists after **dummyfiled** using jquery

Thsi what the html code may look like `<input id='dummyfield'><div class='dummydiv'>`

Comment: is there a case where dummydiv exists even without dummyfield?

Comment: @corroded no it's not the case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the adjacent selector : http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/

```
<input id='dummyfield'><div class='dummydiv'>

if ($('#dummyfield + .dummydiv').length) {
  //field exists 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if `dummydiv` is a child of `dummyfield` then  check

```
jQuery('#dummyfield > .dummydiv').size()
```

if `dummydiv` is sibling of `dummyfield` then check for

```
jQuery('#dummyfield +.dummydiv').size()
```

Comment: a couple of things. `>` checks for `parent > child` and not adjacent. also, `length()` is a property and not a method. I think you may have meant `.size()`

Answer (score 0):

Check-it Out:

**JQUERY:**

```
if($("#dummyfield").next(".dummydiv").length>0)
    alert("Exist.");
else
    alert("Not Exist.");
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dummyfield" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
<div id="divdummy" class="dummydiv"></div>
```

Comment: yeah in if condition only $("#dummyfield").next(".dummydiv").length is enough.

Answer (score 0):

That will help you.

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
```

eg:

```
if($('input[type="password"]').exists())
  alert('exists!');
```